# AppTrackingTransparency permission is mandatory?

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store, privacy, event-tracking

Need some clarification regarding app store app submission according to apple's new privacy policy.

We are using Firebase and Facebook analytics and Facebook share (only sharing a URL) in our app. Only for analytics and crash reporting purposes.

Therefore, do we need to add the app AppTrackingTransparency permission in the IOS app?

We are not using user data for tracking the crash reporting got the user's email only.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: From [Apple’s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency): _“Use the AppTrackingTransparency framework if your app collects data about end users and shares it with other companies for purposes of tracking across apps and web sites.”_ - if you are using Facebook analytics, then I’d say, that definitively falls under this. You are sharing that data with Facebook, and they will likely use it to track users outside of the scope of your app as well.

Comment: "only sharing a URL", is a bit like saying "I only left the front door open", and being surprised when someone walks off with your house contents... Anything touching Facebook is privacy-toxic, and you will absolutely need consent.

Comment: @Synchro - Ohh alright but the data that we are sharing with Facebook doesn't link to any user's personal data (not contains any user id, email, phone number, etc..). That what I'm confused about still do we need to add AppTrackingTransparency ?

Comment: @CBroe Alright thanks!

Comment: Even if you're sharing nothing identifiable amongst your own data, FB will see their IP and OS fingerprint. It really doesn't take much.

Comment: @Synchro ok got it one more thing even that we are not using the app for advertising purpose(not showing any third party ads in the app) but we are using for analytics therefore we need to add the permission in the app side right ?

Comment: Yes. Your "basis for processing" (GDPR term) is an important factor. That (and the requirements of the privacy laws) determines whether consent is the appropriate legal basis for what you're doing – Apple's requirements are obviously secondary to that. Apple is generally getting stricter on privacy, so people are going to get used to being asked for such things anyway.

Comment: @Synchro thanks for the support